# How to define global variable inside callback function for Model.findOne in NodeJS, Express, Mongoose app?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

In my POST route, im finding two documents from my database, each one with model.findOne. Then I´m trying to take from that one of it´s key/value pair and save it into a variable.

I´ve tried window.______ method, ive tried global._____, but nothing seems to work. I´ve ignored the "var" keyword, but whatever I do, I cant access these variables anywhere else.

```
app.post("/match", (req, res, next) => {

  Team.findOne({name: req.body.team1}, (err, team) => {
   if(err) {
      console.log(err);     
   }  else {
      let eloOne = team.elo; // <-- here is the problem part

   }
   });



  Team.findOne({name: req.body.team2}, (err, team2) => {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err)
    } else {
    let eloTwo = team2.elo;   // <-- here is the problem part
    }
  });

  console.log(eloOne)            // <-- here i want to use the variables 
  console.log(eloTwo)    
 });                             // please dont kill me for this code, I've started programing recently
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code.

```
app.post("/match", (req, res, next) => {
Team.findOne({name: req.body.team1}, (err, team) => {
 if(err) {
    console.log(err);     
 }  else {
    let eloOne = team.elo; // <-- here is the problem part
    Team.findOne({name: req.body.team2}, (err, team2) => {
      if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      } else {
      let eloTwo = team2.elo;   // <-- here is the problem part
      console.log(eloOne)            // <-- here i want to use the variables 
      console.log(eloTwo) 

      res.send(' request complete')
      }
    });
 }
 });
});
```

I suggest to use 'async await' or promise atleast.

Comment: This code works perfect, i can acces and work with the variables as I want. I'll just have to learn how promises and async/await works, so that I can add them in. If im not mistaken, they are used to increse productivity? Since when I'm getting to console.log(eloOne) and console.log(eloTwo) they both (.findOne functions) must have been finished, since they are up in the code right? Sorry for being dummy, just getting started with programming. Thanks a lot for the help! Apreciate it!

Comment: @OskarNýč Here is an article that might help you to understand callback, async/await and promises. 
https://www.topcoder.com/blog/callbacks-promises-async-await/

Answer (score 0):

Use promise.all as it will be doing both the network calls in parallel, and hence increase the performance.

```
app.post("/match", async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const [team, team2 ] = await Promise.all([Team.findOne({name: req.body.team1}).exec(), Team.findOne({name: req.body.team2}).exec()]),
          eloOne = team.elo,
          eloTwo = team2.elo;
        console.log(eloOne) 
        console.log(eloTwo) 
      } catch(error) {
        console.log(error); 
      }
    });
```

Comment: Getting this error: TypeError: Promise.all is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Comment: check now, previously i forgot to add await keyword

Comment: Thanks a lot, but now the .findOne actually doesn't return the document from which i can extract the team.elo part. So it gives me error that elo is null. But i guess i just cant write the callback with error and doc part inside that array?

Comment: what does team contains, can you console it

Comment: its null as well :o

Comment: console.log(team); console.log(team2), and comment the lines , eloOne=team.elo and eloTwo = team2.elo,

Comment: Yeah, it´s null.

Comment: i think your db does contain data for the team id

Comment: Well I don't need to acces the ID, i'm capable extracting the elo value that I want. The problem is that when i store it inside a variable inside that .findOne function, i cant access it outside that funciton. And with that code you posted above, i only get access to a huge object, from which i cant extract the elo. My code was working just fine, i'll just need to add the async and await. But the main problem remains the same. Why I cant access the variables declared in .findOne outside it, even if I declare them in global scope.